# How can I get the function to take in a 4-bit binary string and return a 64-bit one?

Tags: c++, binary, bit

I've written the function for an LFSR(not even sure if it's correct) but I'm trying to get it to take a 4-bit string as input and return a 64-bit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

void linshift(int s)
{
    int y = 0;
    int count = 0;

    std::bitset<4> lfsr(s);
    std::bitset<4> bit(y);
    do
    {
        cout << "lfsr: " << lfsr << endl;
        bit = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2));
        lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 3);
        ++count;
    } while (count < 4);

    cout << endl;
}
```

My professor suggested using char but then the output is just symbols instead of binary.

Edit: Maybe this will help better explain what I'm trying to ask.

> The seed s is a starting state for the linear feedback shift register.  This is a random 4-bit
>   value.  Produce G(s) by letting the linear feedback shift register generate 64 bits of output.

Comment: `but then the output is just symbols instead of binary`  Symbols are just a way if interpreting binary data.  What do you need the output to be?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. How can we help you?

Comment: @ Eric J. 0's and 1's, for example the first line of output would be `lfsr: 0110` when s = 6.

Comment: @ David Schwartz What I'm trying to ask is if there's a way to input a 4-bit string and have the function return a 64-bit one? Would using `std::bitset` be the way, or should I just use char?

Comment: @Fabio Ceconello That's basically what I'm asking, s is supposed to be the starting state for the lfsr. It's a random integer that's passed through from the main function. The function is to use that integer as a seed to generate 64-bits of output.

Comment: You could just use string stream instead of cout. That way all of the bits would be captured in order and you could return them as a string.

Comment: @Andre - Usually the intended output from a LFSR is a single bit (not the content of the LFSR), so the sequence should be bit = ... ; cout << bit ... ; ... ; while(count < 64);  .  Wiki article [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).

Answer (score 0):

```
 stringstream ss;
 do
{
    ss << lfsr ;
    bit = ((lfsr >> 0) ^ (lfsr >> 2));
    lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) | (bit << 3);
    ++count;
} while (count < 16);
return ss.str()
```

Comment: The sequence should be bit = ... ;  ss << bit;  ... while(count  < 64); . Usually the intended output from a LFSR is a single bit.  Wiki article [LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is a bit more picky about the syntax. Also lfsr[0]^lfsr[2] is a non-maximal lfsr, repeating every 6 cycles. lfsr[0]^lfsr[1] or lfsr[0]^lfsr[3] are maximal lfsrs, repeating every 15 cycles. Note lfsr[0] corresponds to polynomial term x^4, lfsr[1] to x^3, lfsr[2] to x^2, lfsr[3] to x, bit corresponds to the 1 that would correspond to the non-existent lfsr[4].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

void linshift(int s)
{
    int count = 0;
    bitset<4> lfsr(s);
    bitset<1> bit;
    do
    {
// lfsr polynomial = x^4 + x   + 1 = maximal lfsr, repeats every 15 cycles
//      bit = lfsr[0] ^ lfsr[3];
// lfsr polynomial = x^4 + x^3 + 1 = maximal lfsr, repeats every 15 cycles
//      bit = lfsr[0] ^ lfsr[1];
// lfsr polynomial = x^4 + x^2 + 1 = non-max lfsr, repeats ever   6 cycles
        bit = lfsr[0] ^ lfsr[2];
        lfsr = (lfsr >> 1) ^ bitset<4>(bit[0] << 3);
        ++count;
        cout << bit;
    } while (count < 64);
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
        linshift(i);
    return 0;
}
```